# How can i do Multi Line printing in ruby?

Tags: ruby

i want to ask something. I am learning Ruby programming language newly. Im writing a application. However, my question is "How can i multi line print something?" like how it is:

Python code:

```py
print("""

Hey
Hello
Hi

""")
```

How can i do this with ruby?

Comment: In Ruby, string literals can span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

If the string doesn't contain quotation marks you can do it like this:

```
text = "this is
a
multi-line string"
```

Another option would be a here document (heredoc) syntax:

```
text = <<~HEREDOC
this is
a
multi-line string
HEREDOC
```

You can also use a percent string:

```
text = %q(
this is
a
multi-line string
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Three methods that immediately spring to mind:

```
# heredoc format
print <<~MESSAGE
          I
          Am
          Multiline
MESSAGE

# array join
print %w|I am Multiline|.join("\n")

# map
%w|I am Multiline|.map {|x| puts x  }
```

Comment: Or you could just use regular strings, single- or double-quoted

Comment: That `map` should be an `each`, btw.